# Azure Machine Learning One to Many Data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to learn Azure Machine Learning and it seems the data sources for all the algorithms are two dimensional. Is there any way I can use one to many relational tables as a data source? or is it even possible?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible as far as I'm aware :(

However, the general rule is that you should flatten a relational graph into a single array of values.  Remember, though, that you should have one array of values per main entity, it looks to me like your main entity in your example is the one with the Visits in.

Effectively, you'd be saying that all diagnoses are a property of Visit, but because there's potentially more than one, you'd have to have properties such as Diagnosis1, Diagnosis2, Diagnosis3 ...etc.